Android App is not registering to firebase realtime database
I built an app on android studio, created the signup/sign-in page, wrote the code. it worked with one account but recently I tried registering more accounts but it returns a  notification saying "Registration failed The supplied auth credential is incorrect, malformed or has expired." It has also affected the reset password. Below is the activity
            public class ForgetPassword extends AppCompatActivity {
            private EditText emailEditText;
            private ProgressBar progressBar;
            private Button resetPassword;
            FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            String Email;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_forget_password);

            emailEditText = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            Button resetPasswordButton = findViewById(R.id.resetPassword);
            progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

            resetPasswordButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (email.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please enter a registered email",                     
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            emailEditText.setError("Email is Required");
            emailEditText.requestFocus();
            } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
            emailEditText.setError("Valid email is Required");
            emailEditText.requestFocus();
            } else {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            resetPassword();
            }
            });

            }

            private void resetPassword() {
            FirebaseAuth mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(Email).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (task.isSuccessful()){
            Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Please check inbox for reset password link!",  
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            new Intent(ForgetPassword.this, LoginActivity.class);
            //Clear stack to prevent user coming back to ForgotPassword
            startActivity(null);
            finish();
            }else {
            Toast.makeText(ForgetPassword.this, "Something went wrong!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            });
            }
            }


            public class RegisterActvity extends AppCompatActivity {
            EditText email, phoneNumber, userName, password;
            Button btnRegister;
            TextView textLogin;
            FirebaseAuth mAuth;
            FirebaseDatabase database;
            DatabaseReference reference;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_register_actvity);

            btnRegister = findViewById(R.id.button);
            email = findViewById(R.id.inputEmail);
            phoneNumber = findViewById(R.id.inputPhone);
            password = findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);
            textLogin = findViewById(R.id.account);
            userName = findViewById(R.id.userName);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            textLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActvity.this, LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            }
            });

            btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            reference = database.getReference("users");


            String inputEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String pass = password.getText().toString();
            String inputPhone = phoneNumber.getText().toString();
            String User = userName.getText().toString();


            if (inputEmail.isEmpty()) {
            email.setError("Email can not be empty");
            }
            if (User.isEmpty()) {
            userName.setError("User can not be empty");
            }
            if (pass.isEmpty()) {
            password.setError("Min password length should 6 characters");
            }
            if (inputPhone.isEmpty()) {
            phoneNumber.setError("linenumber can not be empty");
            } else {
            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(inputEmail, pass).addOnCompleteListener(new 
            OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActvity.this, "User registered Successfully", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(RegisterActvity.this, LoginActivity.class));
            } else {
            Toast.makeText(RegisterActvity.this, "Registration Failed" + 
            task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            }
            );
            HelperClass helperClass = new HelperClass(phoneNumber, email, userName, password);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("userName").setValue(User);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("email").setValue(inputEmail);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("phoneNumber").setValue(inputPhone);
            reference.child("users").child(inputPhone).child("password").setValue(pass);
            }
            }
            });
            }
            }

